# How do i remove a specific layout from the VBox in Javafx 8

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, javafx

I am trying to make a GUI that allows you to add or remove members to a group. How i did it was for the member view i created a VBox layout to hold all the members. Each member has its own grid layout. When the user presses add member it will add a members layout to the VBox(The area to view all the members). The problem is when i press remove member, it will remove the member below the one i want to remove and on the last member the GUI gives an error saying "Could not remove member: index 2, size 2".

Main Class

```
/**
```

* Main.java
 *
 *  The main class for Section 7 Manager
 */

```
package sba.s7.Main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sba.s7.Main.AlertBox.ConfirmBox;
import sba.s7.Main.Panel.Menu;
import sba.s7.Main.Panel.Member.MemberInfo;
import sba.s7.Main.Panel.Member.MemberMenu;



public class Main extends Application {

    /** Variables */
    /* Imports */
    private MemberInfo mem; // Member Info

   /* Int */
   public final int WIDTH = 715;
   public final int HEIGHT = 700;

   /* String */
   private final String TITLE = "If there is no road, we make one";

   /* Scenes */
   private Stage window;  // Window
   private Scene mainScene;  // Main Scene
   private static VBox infoVbox;  // VBox Layout



/** Start */
/*
 * This is the first method to run when the GUI starts
 */
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    window = stage;

    /* Instantiates */
    mem = new MemberInfo(0);  // Member Info

    /* Layouts */
    // Main Layout
    VBox vbox = new VBox(30);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 0, 0, 30));


    // Info Layout
    infoVbox = new VBox();


    /*
     * Scenes
     */

    /* Menu */
    vbox.getChildren().add(Menu.displayMenu());


    /* Members Scene */
    vbox.getChildren().add(MemberMenu.displayMenu());  // Member Menu
    infoVbox.getChildren().add(mem.displayDir());  // Member Info


    /* Info Panel */
    vbox.getChildren().add(infoVbox);



    /* Window */
    mainScene = new Scene(vbox, WIDTH, HEIGHT);  // Main Scene
    window.setTitle(TITLE);  // Title
    window.setScene(mainScene);  // Scene
    window.setMinHeight(200);  // Min Height
    window.setMinWidth(350);  // Min Width
    window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {  // Close
        e.consume();
        close();
    });
    window.show();  // Show
}



/** Main Method */
/*
 * The main method for the class
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}



/** Close */
/*
 * Performs a proper app close when called
 */
private void close() {
    boolean answer = ConfirmBox.display("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit.");

    if(answer) {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}



/** Getters */
/* infoBox */
public static VBox getLayout() {
    return infoVbox;
}
}
```

Menu Class (Add Member section)

```
/**
* Menu.java
*
*   This is the menu that is displayed at the top of the screen
*/

package sba.s7.Main.Panel;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import sba.s7.Main.Main;
import sba.s7.Main.Panel.Member.MemberInfo;



public class Menu {

    /** Variables */
    /* Imports */
    private static MemberInfo mem;

    /* Int */
    private static int id = 1;
    private static int memSize;



 /** Display Menu */
 /*
 * Displays the menu when called
 */
public static FlowPane displayMenu() {
    /* Window */
    FlowPane lay = new FlowPane();  // GridPane


    /* 
     * Components
     */

    /* Button */
    //------------------------------
    // Add Member
    //------------------------------
    Button addMem = new Button();
    addMem = new Button("Add a member");
    // Action Event
    addMem.setOnAction(e ->  {
        addMember();
    });


    lay.getChildren().add(addMem);  // Adds addMem



    return lay;
}



/** Add Member */
/*
 * This will set the id & add a member
 */
private static void addMember() {
    //----------------------------------------------
    // Makes the id less than the layout size
    //----------------------------------------------
    if(id > Main.getLayout().getChildren().size()) {
        for(int i = id; i > Main.getLayout().getChildren().size(); i--) {
            id--;
        }
    }


    //-----------------------------
    // Adds a member
    //-----------------------------
    mem  = new MemberInfo(id);
    Main.getLayout().getChildren().add(id, mem.displayInfo());

    memSize++;  // Member size


    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    // This will set id to be less than the size of Main layout
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    if(id < Main.getLayout().getChildren().size())
        id++;  // Id
}



/** Getters */
/* memSize */
public static int getMemSize() {
    return memSize;
}
}
```

Member Info Class (The members)

```
/**
```

* MemberInfo.java
 *
 *  This will display member info such as name, rank ect.
 */

```
package sba.s7.Main.Panel.Member;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import sba.s7.Main.Main;
import sba.s7.Main.AlertBox.AlertBox;
import sba.s7.Main.File.SaveFile;


public class MemberInfo {

    /** Variables */
    /* Int */
   private int id;  // Id
   private int row = 2;  // Row



/** Constructor */
/*
 * Constructor for the class
 */
public MemberInfo(int id) {
    this.id = id;  // Id
}



/** Display Info */
/*
 * This will display member info to the scene when called
 */
public GridPane displayInfo() {
    System.out.println("START: " + id);

    /* Window */
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();  // Grid Pane
    gp.setHgap(69);  // HGap
    gp.setVgap(5);


    /* 
     * Components
     */

    /* Label */
    //----------------------------
    // Rank
    //----------------------------
    ChoiceBox<String> rank = new ChoiceBox<String>();
    rank.getItems().addAll("XO", "SOC1", "SOC", "SO", "OP", "JP");  // Choices
    rank.setValue("JP");  // Default Value
    rank.setPrefWidth(100);  // Width

    GridPane.setConstraints(rank, 0, row);  // Constraints
    gp.getChildren().add(rank);  // Adds Rank TextField


    /* TextField */
    //---------------------------
    // Name
    //---------------------------
    TextField name = new TextField();
    name.setPromptText("name");  // Prompt Text

    GridPane.setConstraints(name, 2, row);  // Constraints
    gp.getChildren().add(name);  // Adds Rank Label


    /* Button */
    //---------------------------
    // Save Button
    //---------------------------
    Button save = new Button("Save");
    save.setOnAction(e -> SaveFile.save(rank.getValue(), name.getText()));  // Sets action event

    GridPane.setConstraints(save, 3, row);  // Constraints
    gp.getChildren().add(save);  // Adds the save button


    //----------------------------
    // Delete Member
    //----------------------------
    Button delMem = new Button("Remove Member");
    delMem.setOnAction(e -> {
        removeMember();
    });


    GridPane.setConstraints(delMem, 4, row);  // Constraints
    gp.getChildren().add(delMem);  // Adds the delMem button



    /* House Keeping */
    return gp;  // Returns the layout
}



/** Display Dir */
/*
 * Displays the Director
 */
public GridPane displayDir() {
    /* Window */
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();  // Grid Pane
    gp.setHgap(69);  // HGap
    gp.setVgap(5);


    /* 
     * Components
     */

    /* Label */
    //----------------------------
    // Rank
    //----------------------------
    ChoiceBox<String> rank = new ChoiceBox<String>();
    rank.getItems().addAll("Dir");  // Choices
    rank.setValue("Dir");
    rank.setPrefWidth(100);  // Width

    GridPane.setConstraints(rank, 0, row);  // Constraints
    gp.getChildren().add(rank);  // Adds Rank TextField


    /* TextField */
    //---------------------------
    // Name
    //---------------------------
    TextField name = new TextField();
    name.setPromptText("name");  // Prompt Text

    GridPane.setConstraints(name, 2, row);  // Constraints
    gp.getChildren().add(name);  // Adds Rank Label


    /* Button */
    //---------------------------
    // Save Button
    //---------------------------
    Button save = new Button("Save");
    save.setOnAction(e -> SaveFile.save(rank.getValue(), name.getText()));  // Sets action event

    GridPane.setConstraints(save, 3, row);  // Constraints
    gp.getChildren().add(save);  // Adds the save button



    /* House Keeping */
    return gp;  // Returns the layout
}



/** Remove Member */
/*
 * This will remove a member when called
 */
private void removeMember() {
    try {
        //-------------------------------
        // Removes the member
        //-------------------------------
        Main.getLayout().getChildren().remove(id);
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        AlertBox.display("ERROR", "Could not remove member: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}



/** Getter */
/* id */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

Comment: Based on how I see it, this is an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
Have you tried subracting 1 from id?   
`Main.getLayout().getChildren().remove(id - 1);`      
   
   
When you call `removeMember()`, the current value of `id` is equal  `Main.getLayout().getChildren().size()`

Comment: @ Francis Fredrick Valero That sort of worked. I can now remove the right member but the last two or 3 will still give me the error